# Detect click of a div inside a container

Tags: reactjs

Hi I am trying to detect when a div is clicked that is nested inside of a container.

the goal is to extract the src for an image as a variable.

I want the path to the image

Would this work ?

```
<div className = "container">
    <div onClick{divClicked()} className="column">
      <img alt="" src={props.gif} className="ui image" />
    </div>
</div>


    divClicked() { 
    console.log(props.gif)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set an onclick like that.

```
 <div onClick={divClicked} className="column">
```

this code should work if the `divClicked` function is in the same context.

If this function is a member of a class, you might want to use `this.divClicked`

Additionally if you want to pass parameters to the function you can use arrow functions to do this.

```
     <div onClick={()=>divClicked(someParam)} className="column">
```

Comment: Thank you Sylens Ill check this when I get home. Ty